# Using coalesce() in dataset filter

Tags: delphi, filter, dataset, delphi-10.2-tokyo

```
 // lItems is TDataSet or TClientDataSet
 with lItems do
 begin
   Close;
   Filtered := false;
   Filter := Format('coalesce(%s,0)=%d',[lFieldName,lInteger]);    // lInteger is >= 0, lFieldName is hard coded constant string representing a field name 
   Filtered := true;
   Open;
```

fails on the open statement (also with brackets `(coalesce(%s,0)=%d)`) with

> Field 'coalesce' not found

This is Delphi Tokyo using FireDAC on a FireBird database (I expect it to go wrong on other database types as well).

Any way around this?

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I wouldn't expect `Coalesce` to work in a TClientDataset filter.  Is is basically a server-side routine, which some but not all Sql Servers support.

The expression filter of a TClientDataSet uses a TExprParser (see DBCommon.Pas) to support its Sql-like  filter expressions, and a look through its source code (see the routine `GetSQLToken`) does not support `Coalesce`, in D7 (which is all I have on this laptop), at least.  Also, coalesce is not amongst the items in the `TCANOperator` enumation which effectively defines what syntax TExprFilter and hence TClientDataSet support.

An obvious work-around to this would to be to include the call to Coalesce in the SQL expression used to retrieve the server data for the CDS.

Comment: I can confirm that in Delphi Tokyo's Data.DBCommon.pas coalesce is also not in TCanOperator. Thanks for the added explanation why this fails. I cannot put the coalesce in the SQL expression and use the workaround from my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

FireDAC supports **NVL** and **IFNULL** functions (they are equivalent) in their expression engine, but not **COALESCE**. FireDAC's expression engine (which is used behind the [**Filter**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter) property) is DBMS independent and filtering is performed locally from the internal storage so these functions will work for any supported DBMS, even when it doesn't support them. One exception is for [**TFDTable filter**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Filtering_Records_(FireDAC)#TFDTable_and_Filtering) in specific (live) mode, when FireDAC performs server side filtering.

So instead of **COALESCE** on this line:

```
Filter := Format('COALESCE(%s, 0) = %d', [lFieldName, lInteger]);
```

You can write your filter with **NVL** or **IFNULL** like this:

```
Filter := Format('NVL(%s, 0) = %d', [lFieldName, lInteger]);
Filter := Format('IFNULL(%s, 0) = %d', [lFieldName, lInteger]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A case statement will also fail. You'll have to split out the 0 and >0 cases 'manually':

```
if lInteger = 0 then
  Filter := Format('(%s is null) or (%s = 0)',[lFieldName,lFieldName])
else
  Filter := Format('(%s=%d)',[lFieldName,lInteger]);
```